# Ao fazer login redirecionar para mais de uma página

Tags: php

Por exemplo, estou a validar o login para redirecionar para as páginas de acordo com o nível de acesso:

```
if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1"){
    header("Location: ./index.php/administrativo");
}elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2"){
    header("Location: ./index.php/colaborador");
}elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "3"){
    header("Location: ./index.php/enfermagem");
}elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "4"){
    header("Location: ./index.php/administradorlogistica");
}else{
    header("Location: ./index.php/cliente");
}
```

e funciona bem.

Agora pretendia era para o mesmo nível de acesso redirecionar para mais do que uma página. Não sei se é possível, tentei desta forma para o nível de sessão 4, mas não direcciona:

```
if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1"){
    header("Location: ./index.php/administrativo");
}elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2"){
    header("Location: ./index.php/colaborador");
}elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "3"){
    header("Location: ./index.php/enfermagem");
}elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "4"){
    header("Location: ./index.php/administradorlogistica");
}else($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "4"){
    header("Location: ./index.php/alertas3");
}
```

e também tentei desta:

```
if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1"){
    header("Location: ./index.php/administrativo");
}elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2"){
    header("Location: ./index.php/colaborador");
}elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "3"){
    header("Location: ./index.php/enfermagem");
}elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "4"){
    header("Location: ./index.php/administradorlogistica") AND header("Location: ./index.php/alertas3");
}else{
    header("Location: ./index.php/cliente");
}
```

Mas também não funcionou.

Comment: Bom, isso que você está tentando fazer é meio exótico. Como espera que o navegador mostre duas coisas ao mesmo tempo? quer abrir uma nova aba?

Comment: @Diego Martins não pretendo noutra aba, mas tem razão, não é possível o que pretendo. Eu pensei isso, para não ter que criar uma página igual para cada nível de acesso, mas é onque tenho de fazer

Comment: Eu sei que em python com flask da pra criar templates gerais e modificar eles consoante o nivel de acesso da pessoa ou outras propriedades do utilizador, sendo que flask e um framework, tenta dar uma olhada em frameworks PHP para fazer isso por ti e poupar horas de codigo possivelmente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **header ( string $header [, bool $replace = TRUE [, int $http_response_code ]] ) : void**
>   
> **replace:**
>   The optional replace parameter indicates whether the header should replace a previous similar header, or add a second header of the same type. By default it will replace, but if you pass in FALSE as the second argument you can force multiple headers of the same type. For example:

**Segundo a documentação:** 
O parâmetro opcional **replace** indica se o cabeçalho deve substituir um cabeçalho semelhante anterior ou adicionar um segundo cabeçalho do mesmo tipo. Por padrão, ele será substituído, **mas se você passar FALSE como o segundo argumento, poderá forçar vários cabeçalhos do mesmo tipo.**

**Resumindo:** se você está tentando executar 2 header(), para redicionar para locais diferente, acredito que não será possivel

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

O principio do header() segundo a [documentacao](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php)  é manter numa só pagina, não podes abrir duas paginas numa so aba , isso eventualmente seria um iframe mas já é outra historia, se queres que aja ainda outro redirect na pagina `/index.php/administradorlogistica` a solução seria criar codigo dentro desse ficheiro que te redirecionasse para `/index.php/alertas3` mas ai se não tivesses um IF que determina a condição para não ser redirecionado nunca poderias aceder á pagina `/index.php/administradorlogistica`